# How to write streaming data from MYSQL to aws Kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-kinesis

I am new to aws. I am unable to get the logic for writing or migrating streaming data from MYSQL to aws Kinesis. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have the mysql as rds, may be related https://digitalcommons.calpoly.edu/cpesp/250/   if not, you may need to implement own [KPL](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-producer)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL by itself cannot directly do this but there are a few options:

- [Data Pipeline to S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-incrementalcopyrdstos3.html), with a Lambda triggering and posting changes to Kinesis.
- Application monitoring diff changes and pushing to S3
- Migrate to Aurora MySQL compatible and use [Lambda triggers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html)